# ruby titleize gives space in between alphabet and numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, title

```
1.9.3p385 :010 > "Dell Inspiron 14R Laptop".titleize
 => "Dell Inspiron 14 R Laptop"
```

Did you see that?, A space is added between 14 and R which interferes with my search. Any solution you could think of?

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p385 :015 > "dell inspiron 14r laptop".titleize
 => "Dell Inspiron 14r Laptop"

1.9.3p385 :016 > "dell inspiron 14R laptop".titleize
 => "Dell Inspiron 14 R Laptop" 

1.9.3p385 :017 > "dell inspiron 14R laptop".downcase.titleize
 => "Dell Inspiron 14r Laptop"
```

The alpha numeric whose alpha part is downcased are not treated as titles. So, doing a downcase and titleizing it saves your day.

Comment: but your getting the small `r` in `14r`